# How to UPDATE a column without affecting the others?

Tags: php, sql, forms, post, sql-update

I have this code to update a record from my database, usually i will update only one column, example: on the array i have 6 columns listed, i want to only update the column `keywords`, and the other columns should not me affected.

With this code i can update my records but not a especifc column, because if i write something on the `input name="keywords"` and writte nothing on the other inputs, the column values from these input will be replaced with none values on my database.

**My question is:**

1. How to updade a column without affecting the others?

   ```
   if(isset($_POST["updateBTN"])){    
     $insert_data = array(

       ':title'            => $_POST['title'],
       ':keywords'         => $_POST['keywords'],
       ':img'              => $_POST['img'],
       ':widht'            => $_POST['widht'],
       ':status'           => $_POST['status'],
       ':name'             => $_POST['name'],
       ':height'           => $_POST['height']

     );

   $query = "UPDATE table SET keywords = :keywords, img = :img, widht = :widht, status = :status, name = :name, height = :height WHERE title = :title";
   $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
   $statement->execute($insert_data);

   }
   ```

html:

```
<form  method="post">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="title"> 
    <span data-placeholder="Title"></span>          
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="keywords"> 
    <span data-placeholder="keywords"></span>          
</div>
.
.
.
<button type="submit" name="updateBTN">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change your SQL query to only update the columns for which you have data, or populate any undefined values in `$insert_data` using values retrieved from the database. The first is probably a better idea, but the second is easier to implement.

I haven't written PHP in a bit, but maybe something like:

```
    if(isset($_POST["updateBTN"])) {
      $query = "SELECT title, keywords, img, widht, staus, name, height FROM table WHERE title = :title";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute(array(":title" => $_POST['title']));
      $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $insert_data = array(
        ':title'            => $_POST['title'] ? $_POST['title'] : $row['title'],
        ':keywords'         => $_POST['keywords'] ? $_POST['keywords'] : $row['keywords'],
        ...
      );

      $query = "UPDATE table SET keywords = :keywords, img = :img, widht = :widht, status = :status, name = :name, height = :height WHERE title = :title";
      $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
      $statement->execute($insert_data);
    }
```

Comment: I got a error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 in ... PDO->query('SELECT title, k...')`. People don't update records on this way? I felt that this was a easy question.

Comment: Make sure to double check my code; like I said, I haven't coded PHP in a long time (and so another response to you; I don't update records in this way. I usually use an ORM, or a framework with an ORM such as Django, Ruby on Rails, Phoenix, etc.).

Comment: I updated the answer; let me know if it works so I can sleep at night :).

Comment: Sadly not :/ i got this error: `Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object` and Undefinet variable $row into the array. I'm almost giving up. I think i will use pure SQL on database to update my records. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Changed again; maybe you can try debugging the errors, since you have a system setup?

Comment: This worked, thanks! Sorry for the delay I had other priorities

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to set any of the columns to `NULL` values, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE table
    SET keywords = COALESCE(:keywords, keywords),
        img = COALESCE(:img, img),
        widht = COALESCE(:widht, widht),
        status = COALESCE(:status, status),
        name = COALESCE(:name, name),
        height = COALESCE(:height height)
WHERE title = :title;
```

Comment: The columns is not getting NULL values, i just want to update only one column, when  i set the value only on a single input the others columns get replaced with none values. I tryed your code, but it's getting the same.

Comment: @515948453225 . . . "none" is not a database concept.  What database are you using?  `COALESCE()` should work, assuming the missing values are passed in as `NULL`.

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin.With `none value`, i meant that the value on column remains blank, and not as `NULL`, just a blank space without data.

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
UPDATE table
SET keywords = :keywords,
    img = CASE WHEN img IS NOT NULL THEN img ELSE :img END,
    widht = CASE WHEN widht IS NOT NULL THEN widt ELSE :widht END,
    status = CASE WHEN status IS NOT NULL THEN status ELSE :status END,
    name = CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL name ELSE :name END,
    height = CASE WHEN height IS NOT NULL THEN height ELSE :height END
 WHERE title = :title;
```

Comment: No, it's not even updating my record :/